# Make an array from geoson data from routine machine

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, geojson, osrm

I am trying to make an array from data from leaflet routing machine. I need it to be in this format :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [

                    [
                        -122.404947281,
                        37.7815184928,
                        0
                    ],
                    [
                        -122.409410477,
                        37.7780078698,
                        0
                    ],
                    [
                        -122.510712147,
                        37.7691033683,
                        0
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "\n"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can only get this:
Output:

```
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-1.55654,52.41007,0],[-1.5567,52.41003,0],[-1.55674,52.41002,0],[-1.55677,52.40999,0],[-1.55445,52.413,0]]}
```

Code from the when using leaflet.routine.machine

```
myroutewithout.on('routeselected', function(e) {

  var lineCoordinates = [],
    i,
    latLng;

  for (i = 0; i < e.route.coordinates.length; i++) {
    latLng = L.latLng(e.route.coordinates[i]);
    lineCoordinates.push([latLng.lng, latLng.lat, 0]);
  }

  var json = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [],
    type: 'LineString',
    coordinates: lineCoordinates
  };

   var jsonExport = JSON.stringify(json)
  console.log(jsonExport);

});
```

How do I add the extra stuff at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way in the end and works perfect

```
var geojson = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[]
        },
        "properties":null
    }]
};  



  var lineCoordinates = [],
    i,
    latLng;

  for (i = 0; i < e.route.coordinates.length; i++) {
    latLng = L.latLng(e.route.coordinates[i]);
    geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push([latLng.lng, latLng.lat, 0]);
  }
```